# Rust lazy_static! macro with a post-processed string?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to integrate a fairly complex SQL query using a recursive common table expression (it's about 80 lines of SELECT statement). There are two different queries that can seed the recursion.  I'd like to not have two different 80-line SQL statements differing by one line embedded in my code, thank you, but I would also like to avoid recalculating those expressions on every use, so `lazy_static!` with `include_str!` seems like the way to go.

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref select_kasten_by_title_sql: &'static str = str::replace(
        include_str!("sql/select_kasten_by_parameter.sql"),
        "QUERYPARAMETER",
        "zettlen.title"
    )
    .as_str();
}
```

Except I keep getting:

```
5 |        static ref select_kasten_by_title_sql: &'static str = str::replace(
   |   ___________________________________________________________^
   |  |___________________________________________________________|
   | ||
26 | ||         include_str!("sql/select_kasten_by_parameter.sql"),
27 | ||         "QUERYPARAMETER",
28 | ||         "zettlen.title").as_str();
   | ||________________________-________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   | |_________________________|
   |                            temporary value created here
```

Which puzzles the heck out of me, because I can't determine what function it's referring to. I get that there's a temporary value, but its lifetime should be the duration of this expression, shouldn't it, and once it's set as a static str, that's it, right?

Comment: According on `lazy_static`'s documentation, the initialization expression is run when the static is dereferenced for the first time. The function being referred to is thus an implementation of [`Deref::deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#tymethod.deref).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Splitting up the variables makes it easier to visualize:

```rust
lazy_static! {
  static ref select_kasten_by_title_sql: &'static str = {
    let tmp = str::replace(
      include_str!("sql/select_kasten_by_parameter.sql"),
      "QUERYPARAMETER",
      "zettlen.title",
    );
    tmp.as_str()
  };
}
```

`tmp` is a local variable that is owned by the block scope. You are trying to return a reference to `tmp` - you are trying to return a value that is referencing data owned by the current scope. This is not possible, as the compiler will tell you:

```rust
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `tmp`
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     tmp.as_str()
   |     ---^^^^^^^^^
   |     |
   |     returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |     `tmp` is borrowed here
```

A simple fix is to return the `String` directly, instead of a reference to it:

```rust
lazy_static! {
  static ref select_kasten_by_title_sql: String = str::replace(
    include_str!("sql/select_kasten_by_parameter.sql"),
    "QUERYPARAMETER",
    "zettlen.title"
  );
}
```

If you really, really want to return a `&'static str`, you can use `Box::leak`. I am not recommending you do this, because it provides no benefit over a `String`, but it is an option:

```rust
lazy_static! {
  static ref T: &'static str = {
    let tmp = str::replace(
      include_str!("sql/select_kasten_by_parameter.sql"),
      "QUERYPARAMETER",
      "zettlen.title",
    );
    Box::leak(tmp.into_boxed_str())
  };
}
``
```

Answer (score 2):

`replace` creates a new *owned* `String`, which only lives as long as the surrounding scope, so the slice returned by `as_str` has that lifetime. But you are then trying to assign it to a `&'static str` variable.

You can fix it by changing the type of static variable to `String` instead.

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref select_kasten_by_title_sql: String = str::replace(
        include_str!("sql/select_kasten_by_parameter.sql"),
        "QUERYPARAMETER",
        "zettlen.title"
    );
}
```